# Choco error checksum didn't meet

Tags: windows, installation, checksum, chocolatey, tabby

While installing [tabby](https://tabby.sh/) using [choco](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages?q=tabby) gives `checksum` didn't match error.

```
PS C:\Users\devpa> choco install tabby -y
```

---

```
Chocolatey v2.0.0                                                                                                                                                                              
Installing the following packages:                                                                                                                                                             
tabby                                                                                                                                                                                          
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.                                                                                                                                           
Progress: Downloading tabby 1.0.197... 100%                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                               
tabby v1.0.197 [Approved]                                                                                                                                                                      
tabby package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.                                                                                                                    
File appears to be downloaded already. Verifying with package checksum to determine if it needs to be redownloaded.                                                                            
Error - hashes do not match. Actual value was '7112B623A885DE4C669846469C75A4AF1F0562941201DDF0EDA1E87ADA2FAC4D'.                                                                              
Downloading tabby                                                                                                                                                                              
  from 'https://github.com/Eugeny/tabby/releases/download/v1.0.197/tabby-1.0.197-setup-x64.exe'                                                                                                
Progress: 100% - Completed download of C:\Users\devpa\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\tabby\1.0.197\tabby-1.0.197-setup-x64.exe (89.99 MB).                                                      
Download of tabby-1.0.197-setup-x64.exe (89.99 MB) completed.                                                                                                                                  
Error - hashes do not match. Actual value was '7112B623A885DE4C669846469C75A4AF1F0562941201DDF0EDA1E87ADA2FAC4D'.                                                                              
ERROR: Checksum for 'C:\Users\devpa\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\tabby\1.0.197\tabby-1.0.197-setup-x64.exe' did not meet '55fb4f3aa2f7e45d1a9ed112e4b7d20be25b8babbc24a0a8ce46a157097fa002' fo
r checksum type 'sha256'. Consider passing the actual checksums through with --checksum --checksum64 once you validate the checksums are appropriate. A less secure option is to pass --ignore-
checksums if necessary.                                                                                                                                                                        
The install of tabby was NOT successful.                                                                                                                                                       
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\tabby\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.                                                                                                         
 See log for details.                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                               
Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.                                                                                                                                          
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                               
Failures                                                                                                                                                                                       
 - tabby (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\tabby\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.                                                                                  
 See log for details.
```

Why the `checksums` didn't match and is there's a way through which I can fix this *error* and install [tabby](https://tabby.sh/) using [choco](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages?q=tabby)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can happen if the owner of the package mixed versions,
or updated the product while not updating the version number.

You may avoid this error by running :

```
choco install tabby --ignore-checksums -y
```

You will need to verify afterward that tabby is functional, in case the
checksum error was a serious one.

For more information see the article
[Chocolatey Package Error - Checksums do not match](https://www.gep13.co.uk/blog/chocolatey-error-hashes-do-not-match).